# How to add content to wordpress loops?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got some if statements for my plugin that I would like to execute for every post.

For now, lets just say I want to add "Hello World" to every post

I've tried quite a few things, but I can't quite seem to figure this out.

Quite simply, in my plugin I have:

```
add_filter('the_post','testing');

function testing($content){
    echo "Hello World";
}
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong as Hello World doesn't how.
Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Here is the working code on my index.php page of my theme:
http://pastebin.com/xd1ree8W

Id' like to put the if statement at the top, within a function in my plugin, so it loads for every post.

Comment: Depending where you want it maybe trying to `add_filter()` on the `the_content` instead might do the trick. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/need-content-to-show-after-the_post

Comment: I need to add this right after   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

Comment: so technically before the title?

Comment: That depends where you put the title ;)

Comment: Maybe you should just override the template and call the function whenever it is required. But i guess u dont want that process since you are probably making this plugin in order to keep it simple and non-modification to codebase to work right?

Comment: They give some good examples here but they all involves filters that are being called upon Title in such. which might not be workable in your case. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39918/wordpress-hooks-filters-insert-before-content-or-after-title

Comment: But yeah if the information you want out is before `the_content` which doesnt include the `the_title` and you prepend the information it will display between the post title and its content.

Comment: But let me ask also is the information you want to *print* requires it to have the *plugin* process data about the post in that case you want to override the `the_post` with a `add_action`. And then you can use the posts infromation and modify it before it being displayed.

Comment: I've actually got an if statement that runs, which calls some functions from the plugin.  I want to put that if statement in the post loop

Comment: Can you give me maybe an image example of where you want that information to display or any errors you are getting and possibly me or somebody else can construct an appropriate solution.

Comment: I've just added my link into my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this works on my install using it in the `functions.php`

i didnt modify the `get_the_ID()` parts but you could easily use the object like so `$obj->ID`

```
function everypost_func($obj){
    echo 'This is sort of cool';

    if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'other-link', true))
    {
            $url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'other-link', true);
            $status = 200;
            $price = NULL;
            //echo "Looks like you've got other-link selected";
    }
    elseif (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'generic-asin', true))
    {
            $status = 100;
            $asin = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'generic-asin', true);
            //echo "Looks like you've got a generic-asin";

            if($_COOKIE['countrycode'] == "GB")
            {
                    $reg = "co.uk";
                    //echo "and we've detected you're in the UK <br>";
            }
            else
            {
                    $reg = "com";
                    //echo "and we've detected you're not from the UK <br>";
            }
    }
    else
    {
            if(($_COOKIE['countrycode'] == "GB") && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'link-uk', true))
            {
                    $asin =  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'link-uk', true);
                    $reg = "co.uk";
                    $status = 100;
                    //echo "looks like you're in the UK, and we have a UK link<br>";
            }
            elseif (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'link-us', true))
            {
                    $asin =  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'link-us', true);
                    $reg = "com";
                    $status = 100;
                    //echo "looks like you're not in the UK, but we have a US link for you<br>";
            }
            elseif (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'link-uk', true)) {
                    $asin =  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'link-uk', true);
                    $reg = "co.uk";
                    $status = 100;
                    //echo "looks like you're not the UK, but we have a UK link<br>";
            }      
            else
            {
                    $status = 404;         
                    //echo "looks like nothing is here for you<br>";       
            }
    }


    if($status == 100)
    {
            $results = get_aws_details($reg, $asin);
            $price = $results[0][0];               
            $url = $results[1][0];
            $wishlist = $results[2][0];
            //echo "Success";
    }
    elseif($status == 404)
    {
            $price = NULL;
            $url = get_the_permalink();
            $wishlist = NULL;
            //echo "404";
    }
}

add_action('the_post','everypost_func');
```

So taking in consideration that you are doing it in a plugin it will depend on the context you are constructing it.

Example in OOP : `add_action('the_post',array($this,'everypost_func'));`

Maybe try to make it work within the theme file ie `functions.php` then if it works as you are expecting it then move it in your plugin surrounded with all the goodies necessary.

-- *will update more upon OP commentary*

Comment: Interestingly, this works in functions.php, however it doesn't work in my plugin file :/

Comment: Im wondering if I've done something wrong in my plugin.  Can I not just add this function to my plugin file, and have it execute?

Comment: @K20GH if you edit your question to include the plugin construction/execution code and i could make a working edit for it.

Comment: thanks for the offer, however I've resolved it with your code and making a slight tweak to mine.  Someone may have put a closing brace in the wrong place in another function...

Comment: I do have a question though.  How do I pass a variable to this function?

Comment: @K20GH i'm not entirely sure but try maybe if its possible to send it arguments just like that but maybe with a `do_action` it would work. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action .. i will look into it when i get the time.

Answer (score 1):

You have used perfects filter for the add content but you have make slightly mistake in filter function.

here you have need add "hello word" in content. bellow filter fulfilled your requirement.

```
function testing($content){
    return $content. "Hello World";
}
add_filter('the_post','testing');
```

here Hello world add on beginning of the content.

I hope it's work for you.

Answer (score 1):

When I read the headline I thought the following snippet might be what you are looking for. This supposes that your chosen theme uses the

```
the_content()
```

function to render the post content. After browsing through your paste bin I'm not so sure if this snippet addresses the code you put in the paste bin, but I'm leaving it on as it does answer the headline and might point you in the right direction.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_my_content' );
function add_my_content( $content ) {
    return "Hello World, \n" . $content;
}
```